# How can I generate a random point on a line segment?

Tags: javascript, canvas

[Html Canvas Layout example with a line segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10p4U.png)

I'm working with an HTML canvas and drawing line segments. I'd like to generate a random point on the line segment in JavaScript. Given points ( (p1.x, p1.y), (p2.x, p2.y) ), how can I do this, given a modifier between 0 to 1? For example, if the modifier is 0.75, the new point generated would be 75% of the way from p1 to p2.

Comment: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-930571c142e5a454827cca64cd0855be.webp --  But .. In all seriousness and fairness .. What is your logic, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer myself. Here it is if anyone wants it. You need to find the distance between the two points, and then modify the **new point** to fit between them, by scaling both the X and Y coordinates by the scalar, and then adding the result to your first point in order to align the result with your vector.

```
function findPartWay(vector, scalar) {
    var distX = vector.p2.x - vector.p1.x;
    var distY = vector.p2.y - vector.p1.y;

    var modX = (distX * scalar) + vector.p1.x;
    var modY = (distY * scalar) + vector.p1.y;

    return new PVector(modX, modY);
}
```